# Why does my javascript function not work only in iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, custom-function

I am building a website using C# and ASP.NET Core. One of the web pages has a button that is supposed to fill in an input box with your geo location using javascript. I'm having trouble getting Safari in iOS to run the script when I click the button. It seems to work everywhere else I have tested it (PC Desktop on Edge, Chrome, Firefox, iOS Device in Firefox and Chrome).

Here is the function, which is embedded in the bottom of the html page where the button is:

```
<script>
    var form = document.getElementById("locinput");
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(prefillLocation);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function prefillLocation(position) {
        form.value = position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude;
    }
</script>
```

I have tried attaching this function to buttons many different ways.

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Get GeoLoc" mousemove="getLocation();" onclick="getLocation();" />
<button value="iosbutton" type="button" mousedown="getLocation();" onclick="getLocation();">iOS Button</button>
<a id="iosButton"class="btn" data-g-label="button1" href="javascript:getLocation();">Get Location</a>
<input type="button" value="Test" onmousedown="javscript:getLocation();" />
```

In all other browsers, each one of the above "buttons" works. In Safari for iOS, nothing happens.

I did a sanity check by replacing my getLocation() function with an alert function, like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Test" onmousedown="javscript:alert('Hello');" />
```

This works just fine on iOS Safari. This leads me to believe there is some sort of security built in that doesn't allow custom scripts. But I'm sure there is a proper way to do it.

Can someone help me identify why this happens and how to make my custom function work in Safari for iOS?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe there is something blocking the function. 'onclick' should work just fine. Let me run some tests, and I'll get back with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a few things after running some tests:

1. There's nothing wrong with the "buttons", above, Safari on Mac and iOS both respond to `onclick="function()"` just fine.
2. Safari will deny all access to `geolocation` if the page is not accessed via `https:`. Attempting to access `geolocation` with `http:` will throw an error that is viewable in the console, but otherwise the error will be silent.
3. If Safari tries to access `geolocation` via `https`, the browser will throw up a dialog saying something like "The website [your_site_name] would like to use your current location.", with "Don't Allow" and "Allow" buttons.

[image]

If the user manages to get through all of those hurdles, `geolocation` will work.

The test code:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="locinput">
  <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Get GeoLoc"
         onclick="getLocation();"/>
  <button value="iosbutton" type="button" onclick="getLocation();">iOS
    Button
  </button>
  <a id="iosButton" class="btn" data-g-label="button1"
     href="#" onclick="getLocation();">Get Location</a>
  <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="getLocation();"/>
</form>
<script>
  const form = document.getElementById('locinput');

  function getLocation () {
    console.log('getLocation()');
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(prefillLocation);
    } else {
      alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
    }
  }

  function prefillLocation (position) {
    form.value = position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude;
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help @terrymorse! This is very helpful information. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to solve my problem. My site is being accessed via HTTPS. At least the URL start with https and safari is showing the lock icon. I'm going to see if I can plug my iPhone into a Mac so I can read the safari debug console.

Comment: I'll post the code above that I tested successfully, maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. This is very perplexing to me. I just tested the live site on my mac using Safari, and everything works fine. So I hooked up my iPhone to my mac, enabled developer tools, and tried to view the console when clicking the buttons. Nothing showed up.
I'm trying to think of other things that could be causing the issue. My device is enrolled with Mobile Device Management by my company. I'm wondering if there is any increased security implemented. This seems unlikely, but I'm going to try on a different iOS device.

Comment: Man I feel dumb. Apparently, a long time ago, I chose to never allow safari to to get my location. So it was auto denying without any warnings. When looking at the console, I say "ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation." So it was user error. Thanks for your help @terrymorse!

Comment: Ha! Glad you got it sorted.